# Change Windows from booting with BIOS to EFI from other OS

Tags: macos, windows-8, boot, mbr

So I have just used `gdisk` to remove the MBR on my Mac's drive because I got annoyed that I couldn't access my fifth partition - but then learned I could with GPT. Now that I did the "conversion" (its rather just like erasing the MBR and overriding it with a `protective MBR`) I am facing this one issue that just smells like it's trying to boot with BIOS/MBR although it isn't supposed to:

```
Couldn't find bootable drive - please insert drive.
```

Aka. it can't find it's partitio since the MBR is gone.

I don't have my windows install around, so I would like to know if I am able to change Window's boot mechanism from Mac OS? It's Windows 8 that's making the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Windows will boot from a GPT disk ONLY if its a 64 bit edition and it's running on [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface).

Most (older)Macs run EFI 1.1, which is not the same as UEFI, which Windows can boot on.

Newer macs, from about 2011 I think, use UEFI (EFI 2.0) and therefore run Windows x64 in UEFI mode just fine.

Comment: My windows is 64bit, and my Mac has EFI and of course my drive is formated with the GUID partition scheme... o.o

Comment: Macs actually have UEFI. See [this lengthy thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=696523). I myself am actually running Windows 8.1 on an old Macbook5,2 in EFI mode.

Comment: @kinokijuf Can you point to your specific post? This should actually be impossible... what is your user handle on MacRumours?

Comment: I don't know what a macbook 5.2 is, but the very last post in that thread is from 2012, by which time Macs were already UEFI.

Comment: MacBook5,2 is a polycarbonate one, afaik from early 2009. Windows 8.1 supports EFI on it, albeit the support is a bit buggy. I did not participate in that discussion, but see [this question](http://superuser.com/q/671660/101850) here of mine.